# Error when connecting to Mongo DB Hosted in a container

Tags: mongodb, docker

Ive installed Docker locally (mac) and tried to run a docker container using the following command.

```
docker run -it -p 27017:27017 mongoImageId
```

But when I tried to login in to the container via the mongo terminal client, Im getting the following error.

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "userName" -p "password" --authenticationDatabase "sampleDBName"
```

---

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/
2018-07-23T13:41:53.423+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'  :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

But if I try to build the same image in an aws ec2 instance, it connects without a hazel. Does any one else also encountered the same issue and was able to find the root cause ?

Ref.
[1] - https://github.com/aashreys/docker-mongo-auth

Comment: Try launching `docker run` with `--net=host` option to share localhost interface between your docker and host. 
Other possibility is change 127.0.0.1 by your local docker ip: `172...`

Comment: Thanks , using the local ip resolved the issue for me!

Comment: Are you running the `mongo` command from the host, or another container?